# C++ Applying rules to broken up strings

Tags: c++, string, split

I am a bit lost. I am trying to solve an example problem from the book that has me apply a few rules to a string that I've previously split into words.

Beginning with rule 1, I need to add a hyphen between words that have the pattern `vowel-consonant-consonant-vowel`, so for example the word `rules` will become `ru-les`.

However rule 2 states that if the pattern is `vowel-consonant-vowel` I should hyphenate before the consonant unless the second vowel is an e and occurs at the end of the word. I imagine I will need to use nested if-statements to apply these?

I've got all of the words separated using an `istreamstring` named `newWords`, but how can I add a hyphen inbetween `VCCV` to become `VC-CV`? The book has no mention of what kind of process or functions to use in this scenario. I apologize for the basic question, I am doing my best through research but have gotten stuck at this point. I greatly appreciate any assistance, thank you for your time.

Comment: _but how can I add a hyphen inbetween `VCCV` to become `VC-CV`?_ Did you even try to look at the documentation of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). It has an [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) method, that you  can use for inserting characters.

Comment: So I would use an if-statement with the appropriate condition specified, and then insert if it passes?

Comment: "I imagine I will need to use nested if-statements" - not necessarily. `if(a) { if (b) { std::cout << "A and B"; }}` can also be written as `if (a&&b) { std::cout << "A and B"; }`. In practice, you choose what's most readable for humans; the computer doesn't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my complete solution.** I use the command line arguments as the source of the words to process. The code checks each position within word to see if Rule1 or Rule2 applies. If a Rule applies at a given index within the word, the rule is applied at that index, and then the loop continues searching the rest of the word looking for more rules to match.

After all the words are processed, it outputs the processed words which may or may not be hyphenated. Each command line argument is output on a single line.

Here is some sample output: (my bash promot is the ">" char)

```
> hyphenate
usage: hyphenate <string to hyphenate>

> hyphenate "HELLO World! You Rule!" Test Evil One
HEL-LO World! You Ru-le! 
Test 
E-vil 
One
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::istringstream
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <cctype>       // std::tolower

using namespace std;

void DisplayUsage(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "usage: hyphenate <string to hyphenate>"  << endl;
}

bool IsaVowel(char c) {
    bool Vowel = false;
    // Simplify switch by using tolower to convert uppercase to lowercase
    // Only 5 cases to consider
    switch(tolower(c)) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u': 
            Vowel = true;
    }
    return Vowel;
}

bool IsaConsonant(char c) {
    // A character is a consonant if it is alphabetic and not a vowel
    return isalpha(c) && !IsaVowel(c);
}

bool VCCV(string s, int idx) {
    bool matchFound = false;

    // Only check for the pattern if there are enough characters past idx
    if (idx+3 < s.length())
        // return true only if see a VCCV pattern
        if (IsaVowel(s.at(idx)) 
                && IsaConsonant(s.at(idx+1))
                && IsaConsonant(s.at(idx+2))
                && IsaVowel    (s.at(idx+3)))
            matchFound = true;

    return matchFound;
}

bool VCV(string s, int idx) {
    bool matchFound = false;

    // Only check for the pattern if there are enough characters past idx
    if (idx+2 < s.length())
            // return true only if see a VCV pattern
            if (IsaVowel(s.at(idx)) 
                && IsaConsonant(s.at(idx+1))
                && IsaVowel    (s.at(idx+2)))
            matchFound = true;

    return matchFound; 
}

bool VCe(string s, int idx) {
    bool matchFound = false;

    // VCe matches if VCV matches, and idx+2 is the last letter, and its an e
    if (VCV(s,idx) && (idx+2==(s.length()-1)) && (s.compare(idx+2,1,"e") == 0))
        matchFound = true;

    return matchFound;
}

bool Rule1(string s, int idx) {
    return VCCV(s,idx);
}

bool Rule2(string s, int idx) {
    return VCV(s,idx) && !VCe(s,idx);
}


// This program assumes compiled using the -std=c++11 standard
int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    if (argc < 2) {
        // Did not provide a string to hyphenate, display usage and exit
        DisplayUsage(argc, argv);
        return -1; // Error
    }

    // Process each of the supplied parameters which may each contains multiple words
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        // Get the next command line parameter
        istringstream newWords(argv[i]);

        while (!newWords.eof()) {
            string nextWord;
            newWords >> nextWord;

            // Scan the next word to see if any rules apply
            for(int j=0; j<nextWord.length(); j++) {
                if (Rule1(nextWord, j))
                    nextWord.insert(j+2,"-");
                if (Rule2(nextWord, j))
                    nextWord.insert(j+1,"-");
            }

            cout << nextWord << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

To compile this, save it in file hyphenate.cpp and then compile it with the -std=c++11 option.

```
g++ -o hyphenate -std=c++11 hyphenate.cpp
```

Comment: We've barely touched on functions in class, it's incredible to see how they are used in practice. Thank you so much for your time on this, I'm not sure I could've figured it out completely on my own. I will continue to toy with this solution to fully understand how it works.

Comment: It was a lot of fun to take your spec and make main() read like English. Tough to do without functions to help! Please also upvote the solution Laura (hit the up arrow) so others will be pointed to this solution if they look for it.
Good luck with your course!